# Анимированный ползунок

Tags: wpf, .net

Всем добрый день! Подскажите, если кто знает, как лучше сделать анимацию ползунка.
Мне его нужно плавно перемещять в горизонтальном направлении. У него есть 4 точки остановки, каждая точка соответствует нажатой кнопке.
Пока что я остановился на элементе Slider, но есть мысль сделать простой прямоугольник, который будет ездить влево-вправо, т.к. никакие события мыши или клавиатуры он обрабатывать не должен. Что будет сделать быстрее?

Comment: Не совсем понял что вам нужно, но почему бы просто не анимировать `TranslateTransform` объекта? Допустим вот накидал [простенький пример](https://pastebin.com/i4NsjZqR), который поочередно передвигает "ползунок", результат будет [таким](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1uyT.gif). Остается только накидать логики взаимодействия с элементом (двигать мышью, определения расстояния для движения и др.).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо огромное, почти то, что нужно. У меня анимация будет инициироваться не щелчком мыши, а нажатием на одну из кнопок и для каждой кнопки свое смещение. Получается, что описание триггеров нужно выносить в код кнопки? Нельзя ведь в коде описывающем Border сослаться на нажатие какой-либо кнопки и начать анимацию?

Comment: А для этого уже используйте привязки. Я бы на вашем месте сделал свой контролл, у которого было бы DependencyProperty (скажем id элемента) и дальше просто добавил бы пару триггеров под каждое положение, которые были бы привязаны к этому свойству.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо, попробую. Еще небольшой вопрос: Вы не знаете случаем можно ли задать конечное положение по оси X относительно другого элемента. То есть нужно сначала узнать координату другого элемента. Есть возможность это сделать?

Comment: Привязать что либо - легко `{Binding ElementName=ElementName, Path=ElementProperty}`, но как привязать координаты, тут я уже не знаю как помочь...